# Does oozie provide any performance optimizations in terms of I/O?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distributed-computing, oozie

Since oozie is a workflow engine for Hadoop platform, does it improve the performance of execution of a DAG dependencies of MapReduce jobs?

I mean, since the output of one MapReduce job is given as input to the next MapReduce job in the DAG, does oozie provides any mechanism for storing the intermediate results in memory and thus saving I/O.

Or is it just a workflow manager, that coordinates a series of dependent MapReduce?

Want to know how internally oozie works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a workflow manager. It doesn't change how, say, MapReduce works even though it runs M/R jobs.

What you are describing is much more like what [Apache Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/) does. I'm not aware that Oozie integrates directly with Spark yet, but, it can't possibly be difficult or far off.

Answer (score 0):

It is "just a workflow manager, that coordinates a series of MapReduce" jobs. It uses the same mechanisms to execute jobs as using the command line.